# Minecraft Prevent Mob Despawning

Tags: command, minecraft

I am using a 1.12.2 ForgeOptifine Version to play Morph Hide & Seek with my Friends. So I have to place many Passive mobs in order for the hiders to blend, but the mobs despawn and I can't nametag them as the hiders will morph into mobs that do not have name tags so the hiders will lose easily. Is there any command to disable mob despawning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is.

As you may know you can spawn a mob that wouldn't despawn by adding PersistenceRequired:1b tag to it.

For instance, to summon a never despawning zombie you can
`summon zombie ~ ~ ~ {PersistenceRequired:1b}`

To make already spawned mobs have the tag you can

```
execute as @e[nbt={Health:20.0f},type=zombie,tag=!modified_zombie] run data merge @s{PersistenceRequired:1b}
```

and then

```
execute as @e[nbt={Health:20.0f},type=zombie,tag=!modified_zombie] run tag @s add modified_zombie
```

Hope this works!!!!!!